# python odbc Error opening connection

Tags: sql-server, python-2.7, odbc

In 2009 I wrote a python (Python 2.6) script to download data from a remote SQL Server 2005 database using adodbapi.  It continued to work through this year, when a motherboard failure and a corrupted disk image required reloading Windows and reinstalling everything.  Since then I have been unable to run the script.  At first the error message was

> ImportError: No module named System

Downloading Python2.7 solved that problem, but now I am consistently receiving the error:

> adodbapi.apibase.OperationalError: (InterfaceError("Windows COM Error: Dispatch(
>   'ADODB.Connection') failed.",), 'Error opening connection to "Data Source=DASH;Initial Catalog=DashMIP"')

When I check the database logs, I see no attempted login.
I'm running Windows XP, and have set up the Data Source to use Windows Authentication.

Comment: I'm recently running into something similar. I came back to work after a week of vacation to find a passel of source code changes and our Python scripts no longer running. If I find anything, I'll let you know.

Comment: After a little more checking, my error was due to a bad sys.path and, to clarify, I only got the first error, not the second one.